# why String not get localised?

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-getx

I use getxcontroller, in it there is a String like this:

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  String testString1 = 'test1'.tr;

  testMethod(){
   String testString2 = 'test2'.tr;
 }
}
```

After I trigger some localise method:

```
var locale = Locale('de', 'DE');
Get.updateLocale(locale);
```

testString2 is fine to be translated into German, but testString1 not works, since I will update value of testString1 in other method, and testString1 should have initial value.

I tried RxString/.obs, but not works, what is the right way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
String testString1 = 'test1'.tr;
```

`testString1` gets set the moment the controller is created and will never change after, even if you update the locale. What you could do is turn it into a getter so it gets the latest translation everytime it's accessed like

```
String get testString1 => 'test1'.tr;
```